# How to update googleMap marker from a client app (via socket)

Tags: android, google-maps, sockets, client, server

Hello it's my first post on stackloverflow i am begginer programmer and i'll try to explain my problem as best as i can .

First of all let me tell you that the code is from online tutorials and i would like to ask you a few things if anyone knows to answer me.

Let's start with the code...

```
 public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras)
    {

        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                try
                {
                    Socket connection;
                    connection = new Socket(textIp.getText().toString(), Integer.parseInt(textPort.getText().toString()));

                    DataOutputStream dos,dos1;
                    dos1=new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
                    dos = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
                    dos.writeDouble(lat);
                    dos1.writeDouble(lon);
                    dos.flush();
                    dos.close();
                    dos1.flush();
                    dos1.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });
        t.start();
    }
```

as you can see i am on a "onStatusChanged" method and i am trying to send my coordinates from gps to a server...

Here's my server code that i don't know where to put it.

```
Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    try {
                        ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(6666);

                        while (true)
                        {
                            Socket connection = ss.accept();
                            DataInputStream dIS = new DataInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
                            DataInputStream DIS1= new DataInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
                            // System.out.println("lat"+dIS.readDouble()+"\n"+"Long:"+DIS1.readDouble());

                            dIS.close();
                            DIS1.close();
                            connection.close();
                        }


                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
            t.start();
```

okay now my server code contains those lines

```
LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat, long);
 //lat,long=are not initialized it's just for me to try to explain
                 MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions()
                         .position(latLng)
                         .title("I am here!");
                 mMap.addMarker(options);
                 mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
```

okay now if i give coordinates manually it will pop up a marker in the map and will say "you are here" but i want to give the coordinates from the client and while the client moving the marker(server app) updating and moving on the map too

Some of my questions....

**Question1:** Do i need another "onStatusChanged" method on server?
**Question2:** Do i need to synchronize threads? Also why i use threads?

I would like to give me ideas in order to search and read!

If you can't understand what my problem is please tell me i'll try to explain it again and be more specific if i need to...